# What is a suitable material for a cathode in electroplating experiment?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, electroplating

I am going to do an electroplating experiment, whereby I will be using a **Cu(NO3)2** solution to plate onto a cathode.

What is an easily accessible cathode which I can use for this? Would a **strip of Ag (s)** be sufficient, since it is a weaker reducing agent than Cu(s), and should therefore not react with any of the solution? And furthermore, using a strip maximises surface area and there will be a more noticeable change in mass of the cathode?

I am performing these at standard conditions.

Comment: Certainly worth trying. Presumably you will be weighing the silver cathode before and after. If it works well, let us know!